# Axios put request with path variable

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, postman, localhost

I am trying to make a PUT request with Axios to update a Profile schema I have. I am able to update the Profile Schema with Postman as seen below but when I use axios I am getting a network error. Any insight on how I can fix this issue would be much appreciated!!!

[image]

Here's the body of PUT request in Postman as well...[image]

Finally, here is the code where I make the axios PUT request

```js
axios
  .put(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/profiles/${id}`,
    {
      bio: "updating bio!!!!",
      friends: null,
      postHistory: null,
      list: null,
      profilePic: "this is my new image link",
    },
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ${token}`,
      },
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log("modified a user profile successfully");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log("error in modifying a user profile");
  });
```

I am currently getting a Network Error, with the exact error shown below

```
Network Error
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:14 in createError
at node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:117:24 in handleError
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:609:10 in setReadyState
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:396:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/_EventEmitter.js:135:10 in EventEmitter#emit
```

When I do the command

```html
curl -X PUT -v "http://localhost:3000/api/profiles/{6233c8393ea07b03841ea787}"
```

the output is

```js
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:3000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> PUT /api/profiles/6233c8393ea07b03841ea787 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.78.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
< Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
< Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
< Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-origin
< X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
< Expect-CT: max-age=0
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
< X-Download-Options: noopen
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Origin-Agent-Cluster: ?1
< X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 57
< ETag: W/"39-ZOIs/1GD8EVMpSJwxt0l7LYxxZY"
< Date: Fri, 18 Mar 2022 02:44:22 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

When adding the command

```
console.error(error.toJSON())
```

the corresponding output is

```
Object {
  "code": undefined,
  "columnNumber": undefined,
  "config": Object {
    "adapter": [Function xhrAdapter],
    "data": "{\"bio\":\"updating bio!!!!\",\"friends\":[],\"postHistory\":[],\"list\":[],\"profilePic\":\"this is my new image link\"}",
    "headers": Object {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Authorization": "token eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI2MjMzYzgzOTNlYTA3YjAzODQxZWE3ODQiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkplbGxvIiwicm9sZSI6IkNMSUVOVCIsImlhdCI6MTY0NzU3MDc4MiwiZXhwIjoxNjQ3NzQzNTgyfQ.zfNaxmamPF_agsuITm3Z9jPSMCtIBpH9fsZhvZ30-Xs",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "method": "put",
    "timeout": 0,
    "transformRequest": Array [
      [Function transformRequest],
    ],
    "transformResponse": Array [
      [Function transformResponse],
    ],
    "transitional": Object {
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
    },
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/profiles/6233c8393ea07b03841ea787",
    "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus],
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  },
  "description": undefined,
  "fileName": undefined,
  "lineNumber": undefined,
  "message": "Network Error",
  "name": "Error",
  "number": undefined,
  "stack": "createError@http://10.203.251.235:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:118636:26
handleError@http://10.203.251.235:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:118539:27
dispatchEvent@http://10.203.251.235:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:35194:31
setReadyState@http://10.203.251.235:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:34326:33
__didCompleteResponse@http://10.203.251.235:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:34134:29
emit@http://10.203.251.235:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:2841:42
__callFunction@http://10.203.251.235:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:3678:36
http://10.203.251.235:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:3406:31
__guard@http://10.203.251.235:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:3632:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://10.203.251.235:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:3405:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]",
  "status": null,
}
```

In addition, my package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "jellyclient",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.6",
    "ionicons": "^6.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.2",
    "native-base": "^3.3.7",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-feather": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-unordered-list": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: @Phil Axios is running via Node

Comment: Hi, when I added console.error(error.message, error.response?.data) , what is outputting is Network Error, undefined

Comment: @Phil , yes it is, it is all running on the same host

Comment: Can you verify that the server running on port 3000 is seeing the request at all... If so can you log the request. Then you can try with postman to see what the request looks like, and try again with axios to see what it looks like, comparatively you should be able to find difference(s). And if you aren't seeing the request at all, then it is likely because you are different host or the hosts can't communicate because of port blocking etc.

Comment: @Phil, Hi, I am running my app by using npm (I type npm run start on my terminal), when I try the CURL command, the output I get is  * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"message":"Please provide a valid authentication token"}%

Comment: @Phil I think I am able to communicate with the server, I do not see any error message, the output is expected because I didnt pass an auth token with the curl command

Comment: Well based upon that conclusion... I would say there must be logic on the server that would result in it never sending a response thus it would just timeout...

Comment: Ok, can you please change your error handling to `console.error(error.toJSON())` and [edit] your question with the full output. That should show the request and pretty much everything else required to debug this. You can redact the `token` if you want but given these are all local services, it's not exactly sensitive

Comment: @Phil Just added the output, thank you so much for dedication

Comment: Wait a second. I see `react-native` libs in that stack trace. Where **exactly** is this code running? Are you opening your app on a device (phone, Expo, etc)?

Comment: @Phil I am running the app on my phone through Expo, sorry for the confusion

Comment: You need to use the external address of your API server. The requests are made from the device running the app so `localhost` obviously isn't going to respond

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are sending Authorization token as `token ${token}`. Usually prefix is the `bearer` and not `token`.

```js
axios({
  method: 'put',
  url: `http://localhost:3000/api/profiles/${id}`,
  data: {
    bio: "updating bio!!!!",
    friends: null,
    postHistory: null,
    list: null,
    profilePic: "this is my new image link",
  },
  headers: {
    Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
  },
});
```

Comment: [`axios.put()`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosputurl-data-config) is just a shortcut to `axios()` with all the same configuration as in your answer. They are identical

Comment: bearer ${token} and token ${token} are for two different types of authorizations.... So tempted to give -1...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but I am still getting a Network Error when trying this

Comment: Yes, I used different syntax, but the code is not the same. Value of Authorization header is different. @Phil

Comment: OP would get a 401 response if the authorisation was incorrect. I suspect OP's API service isn't actually running on the same host

Comment: But then it would not work in Postman either. Maybe it's CORS.

Comment: @fabiocontreras is your `Authorization` header in Postman prefixed with `token` or `Bearer`?

Comment: Not CORS, OP is running this in Node. Also, when I say _"same host"_, I mean the same host as the NodeJS process. Obviously the device running Postman is on the same host

Comment: Oh, I see. I just saw that in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Alright after doing some research I believe you might have a broken hosts file and/or network lookup... 
For example if you try your axios put request with

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/profiles/${id}
```

I bet you would find it works with the same setup you have (calling 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost). This is because localhost isn't inherently your local machine however the hosts file generally points it to your machine (127.0.0.1). 
**Further** I would like to point out that Postman automatically **converts** **localhost to 127.0.0.1** behind the scenes, thus why it works so well. 
Give this a try and if it doesn't work attempt to change it to 0.0.0.0:3000 as this would indicate an odd port binding...

Comment: OP's using react-native and running this on their phone . Good guesses though

Comment: Ah alright makes sense...